# Deleting UIImageView - Obj C

Tags: objective-c, image

So I have a void method that is working as a death for an enemy. So here is that method.

```
-(void)enemiesDead {
    if (enemy1health <= 0) {
        [self slime1DeathAnimation];
        enemy1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
    }
    if (enemy2health <= 0) {
        NSLog(@"2 dead");
    }
}
```

As you can see in the top if method that I am playing an animation and then setting that image to blank. Now what I want to do is just delete the UIImageView "enemy1". Just completely delete it. I'm not using cocos2d or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call removeFromSuperView method on enemy1 object and then make it nil in that if conditions instead of making the image value as nil. Like this

```
[enemy1 removeFromSuperView];
enemy1 = nil;
```

PS:-

There is a reason why you have to set the value of the object to nil that you have just removed from its super view. If you want to know it than just shout.

Comment: shouldn't you [release] that as well?

Comment: when you do remove from super view the retain count of that object is reduced by one. Unless you have called retain on that object purposely after adding it to the view, you should not other wise the app will crash getting a sigkill.